# DragDrop feature : disallow movable object to move out of screen ( able to go out of screen)

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I added dragDrop feature provided by android in my app, but that object is able to go out of screen and getting cut. Is there any way to prevent that from going out of screen. Please help me to fix this issue :

Code I used is :

For Draggable object :

```
private void setDragListenerToMovableObject(View view) {
    ClipData dragData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);

    view.startDrag(dragData, shadowBuilder, view, 0);

}
```

For container :

```
  llMainAnswersContainer.setOnDragListener(objectDragListener);

  private View.OnDragListener objectDragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View layoutView, DragEvent dragevent) {

        int action = dragevent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not check for x and y values of dragged view, to see if its not greater then screen's dimension?

Comment: No, its provided only these method described above.

Comment: dragevent.getX(), dragevent.getY() returns X and Y coordinate of the drag point. You can work with it.

Comment: I know this... but how to manage this?

Comment: If I have written my own code using touchListener then I could have managed that.. but its internal code of android class..